# How can I mount Google Drive File Stream before launchd user agents start?

Tags: command-line, bash, launchd, login-items, google-apps

I have a simple backup `bash` script that dumps the output of `pg_dump` for a PostgreSQL database into a Google Drive File Stream directory.

This `bash` script is referenced by a `launchd` user agent.

The XML file for the user agent runs the script with a `StartInterval` key.

In theory, this means that the script should run once at login, and should then repeat according to the `StartInterval` key's integer.

My issue is that Google Drive File Stream doesn't seem to be mounting the relevant volume in `/Volumes` in time for the *first* instance when the script in the user agent is supposed to run. I'd like the script to run at login successfully.

The [now deprecated](https://gsuiteupdates.googleblog.com/2017/09/drive-file-stream-from-google.html) Google Drive desktop app used to have a permanent folder on the filesystem, but now the Google Drive File Stream seems to need to mount at login, and it's no mounting quickly enough for the `launchd` agent.

Manually stopping, unloading, loading, and restarting the agent a few seconds after login works fine, once the directory in `/Volumes/GoogleDrive` actually exists.

**How can I reliably mount the Google Drive File Stream folder in `/Volumes` before this other `launchd` agent starts?**

I'm on macOS 10.12.6 (16G1212).

Comment: I think this link may help. [How to instruct launchd to wait for volume mount?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19449288/how-to-instruct-launchd-to-wait-for-volume-mount)